# How do I connect a jupyter notebook to an existing IPython kernel?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter

I am attempting to connect a jupyter notebook to a IPython kernel which was started outside of a jupyter notebook server via [`IPython.kernel_embed()`](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.html#IPython.embed_kernel).

I can attach to it just fine with [`jupyter console --existing` and `jupyter qtconsole --existing`](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Connecting%20with%20the%20Qt%20Console.html) but I cannot do it with `jupyter notebook` as the notebook does not support the `--existing` flag. As mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/4066) this is not because of any technical limitation, but rather because it would be confusing from a UI perspective.

I am successfully able to interact with a kernel from a jupyter notebook with

```
from jupyter_client import BlockingKernelClient
client = BlockingKernelClient()
client.load_connection_file('/Users/ebanner/Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-10962.json')
client.start_channels()
```

and issue [`client.execute_interactive()`](http://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/client.html#jupyter_client.BlockingKernelClient.execute_interactive). However I would really like to avoid running `client.execute_interactive()` in each and every cell.

I have tried several things. First I tried changing the `c.ConnectionFileMixin.*_-port` variables in `jupyter_notebook_config.py` and also writing my own custom kernel manager and setting it via `c.NotebookApp.kernel_manager_class` to

```
from tornado import gen, web
from jupyter_client import KernelManager
from notebook.services.kernels.kernelmanager import MappingKernelManager

class ExistingMappingKernelManager(MappingKernelManager):
    """A KernelManager that just connects to an existing kernel."""

    @gen.coroutine
    def start_kernel(self, kernel_id=None, path=None, **kwargs):
        kernel_id = 1
        km = KernelManager(kernel_name='python3')
        kc = km.client()
        kc.load_connection_file('/Users/ebanner/Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-10962.json')
        kc.start_channels()
        try:
            kc.wait_for_ready()
        except RuntimeError:
            kc.stop_channels()
            raise
        raise gen.Return(kernel_id)
```

but the approaches have all failed thus far.

The most promising route seems to be overriding [`KernelManager._launch_kernel()`](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_client/blob/master/jupyter_client/manager.py#L188-L193), though I am not sure what to override it with as it currently returns an instance of `subprocess.Popen()` on the kernel process started by `ipykernel`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I wound up creating a hacky kernel manager which seems to do the job.

https://github.com/ebanner/extipy

The only caveat is that you have to disable message authentication to get it to work because jupyter was complaining that the expected message signature didn't match.

More discussion here

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jupyter/qamkem52Xn0