# Connecting a jupyter notebook to an existing and running ipython kernel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, tornado, jupyter-kernel

**Short version:** I have a software running its own jupyter kernel. I want to connect to this running kernel from an external source. This works fine with the `--existing` option of `jupyter console` but `jupyter notebook` doesn't have such a functionality.

My issue is more or less this one: [How do I connect a jupyter notebook to an existing IPython kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48777538/how-do-i-connect-a-jupyter-notebook-to-an-existing-ipython-kernel) but the package showed there isn't working properly anymore. I did some code changes to it to make it "work" but I am still running into issues.

**Context:** I have a software with an embedded python3 version. This includes a bunch of c++ extensions made available through this embedded python (in the form of extra built-in modules). These are only available through the embedded python3 started with the software and can be used to interact with the software in various ways (similar to the `bpy` package in Blender for example). It also includes a bunch of modules(understand numpy, pandas, matplotlib and many others etc...)

To facilitate dev, I am "exposing" this embedded python and all modules as a jupyter kernel. I can successfully connect to it externally using `jupyter console --existing  kernel-<id>.json` and get access to all the modules and use them to interact with the software.

**Issue:** There is no `--existing` option for notebooks, or code/script equivalents.

The one solution I found (the one used by the module mentioned here: [How do I connect a jupyter notebook to an existing IPython kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48777538/how-do-i-connect-a-jupyter-notebook-to-an-existing-ipython-kernel)) consists in having a custom kernel manager class, that you can then set with `jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.kernel_manager_class=extipy.ExternalIPythonKernelManager --Session.key='b""'`. It works by overwriting `start_kernel` and as it says: *"It spins up a new kernel through the call to super().start_kernel(...) but then turns its attention to the kernel which was started by an external python process. Kernel restarts will
restart the useless kernel and leave the existing kernel alone."*

This is the core file [class ExternalIPythonKernelManager file](https://github.com/ebanner/extipy/blob/master/extipy/__init__.py), but due to, I imagine, jupyter changes, it fails now (`super(ExternalIPythonKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs).result()` fails as a couroutine doesn't have a `.result()`). Here is my version of `start_kernel` that "works":

```
    async def start_kernel(self, **kwargs):
        kernel_id = await super(ExternalIPythonKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
        if self._should_use_existing():
            self._attach_to_latest_kernel(kernel_id)
        return kernel_id
```

But running `jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.kernel_manager_class=extipy.ExternalIPythonKernelManager --Session.key='b""'` now gets me

```
[I 14:33:17.997 NotebookApp] Kernel started: cdaf10a1-6af9-4f09-9e6f-c6298a0bb16e, name: python3
[IPKernelApp] ERROR | No such comm target registered: jupyter.widget.control
[IPKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: 8563966b-82ac-4f35-8f9b-a98fceaf5f64
```

and when I go to the notebook, my custom Ipython kernel isn't available, only the default "Python 3" kernel.

**Questions:**

- Any idea what could be going wrong? Could it be an issue with me replacing the non working `tornado` specific code with `async/await` based code?
- Is there any other approach to connecting to an existing kernel for jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/2044#issuecomment-1015377299), you can reuse existing kernel by using `--KernelProvisionerFactory.default_provisioner_name=pyxll-provisioner`.

For example:

```bash
STARTUP_CODE="a = 42"

export PYXLL_IPYTHON_CONNECTION_FILE="$(mktemp -d)/connection-file.json"

(printf "%s\n" "$STARTUP_CODE" && sleep infinity) | 
jupyter console --kernel=python3 -f="$PYXLL_IPYTHON_CONNECTION_FILE" &
jupyter notebook --KernelProvisionerFactory.default_provisioner_name=pyxll-provisioner --log-level=ERROR
```

```
0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
[I 2024-03-31 03:19:56.892 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /home/nixos/demo/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 2024-03-31 03:19:56.893 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /home/nixos/peftai/.venv/share/jupyter/lab
[I 2024-03-31 03:19:56.893 LabApp] Extension Manager is 'pypi'.
Warning: Input is not a terminal (fd=0).
Jupyter console 6.6.3

Python 3.11.8 (main, Feb  6 2024, 21:21:21) [GCC 13.2.0]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.16.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: In [1]: a = 42

In [2]: ^[[23;1R[C 2024-03-31 03:19:59.664 ServerApp] 
    
    To access the server, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/nixos/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-93926-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/tree?token=da6ee2fac54afc8591bb9c2de3039036fb15bd5150002e29
        http://127.0.0.1:8888/tree?token=da6ee2fac54afc8591bb9c2de3039036fb15bd5150002e29
WARNING: your terminal doesn't support cursor position requests (CPR).
In [2]: 0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
```

You can see `jupyter console` executes `a = 42` and holds on the kernel, then all subsequential `jupyter notebook` sessions will reuse the existing kernel, where `a` is initialized to `42` out-of-the-box.

[image: Jupyter Notebook]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use [jupyverse](https://github.com/jupyter-server/jupyverse) instead of `jupyter notebook`, as `jupyverse` supports `kernels.allow_external_kernels` and `kernels.external_connection_dir` options to reuse existing running kernels.

```
pip install jupyverse[auth,jupyterlab]
```

```
STARTUP_CODE="a = 42"

CONNECTION_DIR="$(mktemp -d)"
(printf "%s\n" "$STARTUP_CODE" && sleep infinity) | 
jupyter console --kernel=python3 -f="$CONNECTION_DIR/connection-file.json" &
jupyverse --set kernels.allow_external_kernels=true --set kernels.external_connection_dir="$CONNECTION_DIR" --open-browser
```

```
0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
[2024-03-31 21:23:30,474 INFO] Running in development mode
[2024-03-31 21:23:30,488 INFO] Starting application
Warning: Input is not a terminal (fd=0).
Jupyter console 6.6.3

Python 3.11.8 (main, Feb  6 2024, 21:21:21) [GCC 13.2.0]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.16.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: In [1]: a = 42
[2024-03-31 21:23:31,283 INFO] 
[2024-03-31 21:23:31,283 INFO] To access the server, copy and paste this URL:
[2024-03-31 21:23:31,283 INFO] http://127.0.0.1:8000/?token=ce016c609cfa4d8bbcb8c663cbab0c64
[2024-03-31 21:23:31,283 INFO] 
[2024-03-31 21:23:31,289 INFO] Started server process [45786]
[2024-03-31 21:23:31,289 INFO] Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)

In [2]: ^[[27;1R[2024-03-31 21:23:32,425 INFO] Application started
WARNING: your terminal doesn't support cursor position requests (CPR).
In [2]:
```

Now visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/?token=ce016c609cfa4d8bbcb8c663cbab0c64, you will find the existing kernel under the KERNELS tab. Right click it and you will be able to create a new notebook that attaches to the existing kernel.

[image]